# A value returned by a sql script should be used as input for next script

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

1.The following query returns a value:

```
select x , y,(x/cast(y as float)*100) from 
 (select count(distinct t1.ST_NUM) as x
    from table2 t2, 
           table1 t1,
             table t3
where 
  t2.CD in ($CD1)
  and t2.ITM_CD=($ITM_CD)
  and t2.div=($div)
  and t2.div= t1.div
   and t2.scn_cd = t1._scn_cd
   and t1.week_end =t3.week_end 
   and t3.week_end between ($startdate_1)  and  ($enddate_1))a1
   cross join 
   (select count(distinct t1.ST_NUM) as y
         from from table2 t2, 
                   table1 t1,
                   table t3
where 
  t2.CD in ($CD1)
  and t2.ITM_CD=($ITM_CD)
  and t2.div=($div)
  and t2.div= t1.div
   and t2.scn_cd = t1._scn_cd
   and t1.week_end =t3.week_end 
   and t3.week_end between ($startdate_2)  and  ($enddate_2))a2
```

2.The value that is returned by the above query has to be used as follows 
If value Between a and b do this 
If value between d and c do this
I understand that I have to use a case statement. I am not sure how to pass the value as input to the new sql script that I am going to write

Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you need to accomplish it within a single SQL statement?

Comment: There are 3 values being returned from the query viz `x`,`y`,`(x/cast(y as float)*100)` , now the question is what operation you want to do on these 3 values ?

Comment: You have tagged this with `MYSQL` and `ORACLE` - is this for one particular RDBMS or are you going to use this query on both?

Comment: I need to use the last one (x/cast(y as float)*100) only. If this value betweeen 100 and 120, I need to apply a formula..If the value is greater than 120 , I need to apply another formula

Answer (score 0):

Modify the beginning of your query as follows:

DECLARE @x int
DECLARE @y int
DECLARE @z float

select @x=x , @y=y, @z=(x/cast(y as float)*100) from
{rest of query unchanged}

You can now reference @x, @y, and @z in any subsequent SQL statements within the same query.  If you need to be able to access them from a completely different query then you will need to store them somewhere more permanent like a table.

Answer (score 0):

Just write PL/SQL block:

```
begin
for rec in (
select x , y,(x/cast(y as float)*100) as z from 
 (select count(distinct t1.ST_NUM) as x
    from table2 t2, 
           table1 t1,
             table t3
where 
  t2.CD in ($CD1)
  and t2.ITM_CD=($ITM_CD)
  and t2.div=($div)
  and t2.div= t1.div
   and t2.scn_cd = t1._scn_cd
   and t1.week_end =t3.week_end 
   and t3.week_end between ($startdate_1)  and  ($enddate_1))a1
   cross join 
   (select count(distinct t1.ST_NUM) as y
         from from table2 t2, 
                   table1 t1,
                   table t3
where 
  t2.CD in ($CD1)
  and t2.ITM_CD=($ITM_CD)
  and t2.div=($div)
  and t2.div= t1.div
   and t2.scn_cd = t1._scn_cd
   and t1.week_end =t3.week_end 
   and t3.week_end between ($startdate_2)  and  ($enddate_2))a2
) loop
  -- do here your if/case logic. Something like this:
   case 
    when rec.z between a and b then ....
    when rec.z between c and d then ....
  end case;
end loop;
end;
/
```